# Calculate: $|P_{0}(S)|$ and $|P_{1}(S)|$ (sets)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Task from old exam:

> $|S|$ is the amount of elements of a finite set and
>   $$P_{0}(S)=\left\{N \subseteq S: |N| \text{ is even}\right\},$$
>   $$P_{1}(S)=\left\{N \subseteq S: |N| \text{ is odd}\right \}$$
>
> And we know that $|P_{0}(S)|=|P_{1}(S)|$
>
> Task: Let $|S|=n$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Calculate $|P_{0}(S)$ and
>   $|P_{1}(S)|$

I don't really know what we are supposed to do now because we have no specific numbers given. Can I just set some numbers for $n$ and continue? Something like this:

Because we know that $|P_{0}(S)|=|P_{1}(S)|$ we can just calculate it for one of both and we are done(?).

Let $n=1$ then we have that $|S|=1 \Rightarrow P_{0}(S)= \left\{1\right\}$

Hmm no idea at all how could it be done? I'm pretty sure something similar to this will be in the next exam but I cannot solve it..

Comment: You know how many subsets $S$ has (in terms of $n$). You know that every one of them has either odd or even cardinality. And you know that the number with odd cardinality is the same as the number with even cardinality. What does that tell you about the relationship between $|P(S)|$ and $|P_0(S)|$?

Comment: "We know that...". This knowledge must be combined with $|P_0(S)|+|P_1(S)|=2^n$ I guess.

Comment: @drhab: That implies that your equation is something extra not included in this knowledge; I would say that it follows immediately from (some of) this knowledge.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott According to my interpretation the "knowledge" is $|P_0(S)|=|P_1(S)|$ (it is only stated and it is not mentioned where it came from). This allows us to find both cardinalities if we realize that $|P_0(S)|+|P_1(S)|=|P(S)|$, and secondly that $|P(S)|=2^n$. Btw, I fully agree with your comment and see no essential difference.

Comment: @drhab: The knowledge referred to in my original comment is $|P(S)|$, the fact that $|P_0(S)|=|P_1(S)|$, and the fact that $P(S)$ is the (obviously disjoin) union of $P_0(S)$ and $P_1(S)$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I really think we mean the same thing.Btw,  I have found where the [knowledge](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1990179/75923) comes from. I thought it was part of the old exam and was given as some preknowledge to make things less difficult.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott To your first comment, that both these are completely identical? Both are finite, both will include all $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @cnmesr: I’m not following; both what?

Comment: $$|P_{0}(S)| \text{ and} |P_{1}(S)| $$

Comment: @cnmesr: Yes, as long as $S$ is non-empty those two numbers will be the same; that was your previous problem. It’s not true, however, that they can be just any positive integer. They could both be $4$, for instance, if $S$ has $3$ elements; there is no $S$ for which they could be $3$.

Comment: But what is the result then?

Comment: Let me [remind you:](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1990179/prove-for-every-non-empty-finite-set-s-we-have-that-p-0s-p-1m#comment4085898_1990179) **Do not use irrelevant tags.**